# how do I calculate crc32 of a u-boot header in a modified firmware image?

Tags: firmware

I'm trying to modify an openWRT frimware in order to be able to flash it in a router, these are the steps:

> 1. download the latest nbg-419n2-initramfs-kernel.bin use hexedit and
> 2. change first 4 bytes to “Zyxel-like” u-boot magic number FF A8 30 90
> 3. count new CRC32 of u-boot header (64 bytes) and write next 4 bytes (7A
>    BE 7A CE for
>    openwrt-18.06.5-ramips-rt305x-nbg-419n2-initramfs-kernel.bin)
> 4. start tftp server IP 192.168.1.82 rename changed image file to NBG419Nv2.bin
>    and set to tftp server connect any lan port with server press and hold
>    the WPS key button on device and power on after 20-30 second your
> 5. openWrt on ip 192.168.1.1 is ready and waiting

**Step 3** is the problem for me, I can't figure out how to calculate the new CRC32 of the u-boot header. I don't know where does it start and ends, I know it's a 64 bytes however.
What do I use to calculate it? (I tried `crc32` tool on Linux)

Comment: I don't understand step 3 and 4, can you guide me?
Is there a clip to watch?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

You reset the checksum to ZEROs then you calculate CRC32 of the u boot header (from first byte to 64th byte)

```
AA XX YY ZZ 00 00 00 00 ....
```

the first 4 bytes are for magic word; the next 4 bytes are the checksum.